# How to receive toast notifications when the application is closed in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have developed a MVVM windows phone application which has the toast notifications capability. The navigation sequence in my application is login page -> home page -> Messages page . Messages page is the place where all the notifications will be displayed. When the application is closed and when a toast notification is received the Messages page will be opened and shown to the user.

When there are multiple toast messages received when the application is closed and if i click on one of them only that toast message text is displayed.

How do I show all the toast messages received when the application was closed and when user clicks any on one of the toast message ? If that is not possible what is the workaround I can use so that I wont miss any of those messages ?